# File.WriteAllBytes don't working but no error

Tags: c#, .net, file, base64

I'm trying to create a file, from a base64 string. If i try it debbuging locally, it work perfectly, but once deployed in the production server, it doesn't work. I was thinking that it could be because the folder doesn't have permissions to be modified, but there is no error.

This is my code

```
internal static void CopyFileToDir(string document, string userRelId, string name)
        {
            Log.Info(Log.LOG_HANDLER, "Starting function CopyFileToDir");
            try
            {
                var fileName = userRelId + ".pdf";
                var path = @"\\MyDisc\MyFolder\" + fileName;
                var yourBase64String = document;

                Log.Info(Log.LOG_HANDLER, string.Format("CopyFileToDir v2 {0} {1}", userRelId, path));

                Log.Info(Log.LOG_HANDLER, "Getting bytes from base64");
                var fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(yourBase64String);

                Log.Info(Log.LOG_HANDLER, "Generating file in path");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileBytes);
                Log.Info(Log.LOG_HANDLER, "File Generated path");
            }
            catch(ArgumentException ae)
            {
                Log.Error("DatosPersonalesHandler", "Error CopyFileToDir: ", ae);
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dnfe)
            {
                Log.Error("DatosPersonalesHandler", "Error CopyFileToDir: ", dnfe);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Log.Error("DatosPersonalesHandler", "Error CopyFileToDir: ", ioe);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
            {
                Log.Error("DatosPersonalesHandler", "Error CopyFileToDir: ", uae);
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException nse)
            {
                Log.Error("DatosPersonalesHandler", "Error CopyFileToDir: ", nse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("DatosPersonalesHandler", "Error CopyFileToDir: ", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.Info(Log.LOG_HANDLER, "End function CopyFileToDir");
            }
        }
```

If i see the logs, i can see this line "Generating file in path", but then suddenly goes to "End function CopyFileToDir".

Comment: Please try to provide more info. What OS you have on the production server? How do you deploy? What .NET version are you using?

Comment: Also have you checked that `Log.Error` actually works? Check if your logger allows enabling internal log and check it if there is something useful.

Comment: the path variable is hard-coded.  perhaps it cannot be resolved on the production server.  can you reach "\\MyDisc\MyFolder" from the prod server?  Or is it something else like "E:\MyFolder"?

Comment: `\\MyDisc\MyFolder` is a network share. Can the server resolve it, especially given it's a NetBIOS name rather than a full DNS name? And what user are you running this under, does that user have permission on the share?